# Using Selenium, is it possible to create a mock WebElement to use in a unit test?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium, is it possible to create a virtual WebElement to use in a unit test?

```
@Test
public void testIt() {
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  WebElement we = (WebElement)js.executeScript("code to create and return a input element");
  assertTrue("default value", we.getText()); 
}
```

I thought about using a Spy or Mock object, but WebElement doesn't have any "setter" methods and so once I create a WebElement instance, I don't know how I would give it values.

For example, would it be possible to convert a HtmlUnit web element to a Selenium WebElement (that contains attributes)?

```
 final String html = "<html><head></head><body id='tag'><b>text</b></body></html>";
 final HtmlPage page = loadPage(html);
 final HtmlUnitWebElement node = page.getHtmlElementById("tag"); 
 WebElement we = node.findElement(By.xpath(".//b"));
```

Comment: I'm starting to think that there isn't really a reason to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to verify my Selenium-based-scraper and need exactly this (I think). Did you find a solution or alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a proxy class with own implementation. I dont know about Java Selenium, but .Net Selenium has proxy WebDriver that used by PageObjectFactory and this proxy WebDriver returns proxy WebElement class that works in lazy way - it does initialization on the first access to that object.

This may help you as example - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/events . You can check `EventFiringWebDriver` that works like a proxy too and creates proxy `EventFiringWebElement` object.

So you can write own implementation for WebElement that will have setters and you can use them with test data.

Comment: Wow, that looks quite complex.  I'll think about it.