# How do I set Database credential details in gradle.properties file to fetch DB details? Trying to automate UI using selenium

Tags: selenium, build.gradle

How do I set Database credential details in `gradle.properties` file to fetch the DB details?

I'm trying to automate an UI using selenium.
But when I'm trying to fetch the data, I get an error like this:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: You forgot to share details about what you've tried and how this leads to the given exception

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your question Looks like "How can I use a property file in Java?", look at the last answer of this:

[Selenium WebDriver and PageFactory Initialization WebElement From Property File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123591/selenium-webdriver-and-pagefactory-initialization-webelement-from-property-file)